# The entropy of $\max \{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent RVs uniformly distributed on $\{1,\ldots , n\}$
>   and let $Y = \max \{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$. Write an expression for $H(Y)$.

The maximum here confuses me, I do not know how to start. Could you help me?

Comment: Calculate the distribution of $Y$, then use the definition of $H(Y)$. Hint: $P(Y \leq k) = (\frac{k}{n})^3 $

Comment: In general, if $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are indep real-valued RVs and $Y=\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$, then $$\Bbb P[ Y\le y] = \prod_{j=1}^n \Bbb P[X_j\le y].$$  Similarly, if $Z=\min\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$, then $$\Bbb P[Z\le z]=1-\prod_{j=1}^n \big(1-\Bbb P[X_j\le z]\big).$$

Comment: I am sorry but I am still a bit confused. According to the definition of entropy $H(Y)$ should look like this: $H(Y)  = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P_Y(y) \cdot \log \frac{1}{P_Y(y)} = P_Y(y_1) \cdot \log \frac{1}{P_Y(y_1)} + P_Y(y_2) \cdot \log \frac{1}{P_Y(y_1)} + P_Y(y_3) \cdot \log \frac{1}{P_Y(y_3)}$, where $y_i$ denotes the event that $X_1$ is the maximum. So what does $P(Y \le y)$ help me here when the formula requires $P(Y = y)$?

Comment: @3nondatur: $P(Y=y)=P(Y\le y)-P(Y\lt y)=P(Y\le y)-P(Y\le y-1)$.